# Does h2 support PostgreSQL procedures?

Tags: java, postgresql, h2

I am using h2 (with mode=Postgres) for integration and local testing. Migrations are done with flyway. I have some migration scripts that migrate existing data and use Postgresql procedures, i.e. for example:

```
do $$
    declare foo record;
begin
        for foo in (select * from bar) loop
         update something set foobar=foo where bar=foo;
        end loop;
end $$;
```

Is flyway [Java based migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/java) the only viable approach to be considered in this case?

Comment: [Don't use In-Memory Databases for Tests](https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/)

Comment: If you have not testes on the same platform, at least the same RDBMS and version then **you have not tested!**

Comment: We have got a PR check build that runs with postgresql. So tests are run with the version of the DB we have on prod too.